# What is the ideal complexity of a task with (n-1)!/2^(n-1) possible threes?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

I have n elements to connect. Each element has a given length. My objective is to connect all the elements, so that I get one large, with length sum of all elements. The elements must be connected the way the same way they are inputed, but I can choose in what order to connect them. If I connect two elements, they will continue to stay connected. The price of connecting two elements is (the combined length of them (modulo) some value). The objective is to connect all elements together, at the lowest cost.

The lowest complexity I could find is:
O((n-1)!/2^(n-1)), but this can't be the solution, since it is very time-complex.

Comment: It would be useful if you described your goal more clearly, using more notation. It seems that you are given a list of integers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and you are looking for a permutation $\pi$ that minimizes $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (a_i + a_{i+1} \bmod{m})$, for some integer $m>1$.

Comment: Added some clearification

Comment: Can you change "$n$ nodes with value length in an ordered list, " to "$n$ nodes with weights in an order list of numbers"? Length is for edges usually. There is no need to make the problem statement confusing.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Sorry, I am pretty new here. Have tried to clearify now.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Have tried to clearify the goal (objective) now

Comment: It seems that your question just amounts to minimum spanning tree, a well-known problem.

Comment: Can you add a reference to the original material? It is fine if it is in a foreign language.